# Why is float right appearing below float left?

Tags: css, css-float

I have some navigation links, which are image buttons, that I have applied `float: left` to, and I have a login field. The login field, which I have applied `float: right` to, is appearing below the navigation bar. How do I make them side by side?

```
body {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: Baskerville, "Palatino Linotype", Palatino, "Century Schoolbook L", "Times New Roman", serif;
    background-color: #000000;
}

#wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 80%;
}

#top {
    border: medium dashed #F40408;
    text-align: left;
    width: 1500px;
}

#navigation { 
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 20px 3px #E006F5;
    box-shadow: 00 0 20px 3px #E006F5;
    width: 1080px;
    height: 50px;
}

#navigation ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}

#navigation a {
    float: left;
}

#login {
    float: right;
}
```

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to imagine a bit, because there is no html code provided, but I think try to add `position: absolute` to it and your plans to make float left/right will work properly.

Comment: can you provide the html structure even in nav header part only.

Comment: simple test is like https://jsfiddle.net/d2qcqL7r/
and you can do the other adjustments.